# Android Studio Arreglar texto sobrepuesto

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un problema en mi codigo en adroid studio, en mi layout esta todo perfecto como lo quiero pero cuando lo paso a la tablet el texto de description y unit cost se sobreponen uno sobre otro, abajo apareceria texto de productos y estos tambien les pasa lo mismo. He intentado varias cosas, cambien  en texto y en el diseño pero no lo he podido resolver.

Muchas gracias.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/create_replen_request_header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_replen_color"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="265dp"
    android:paddingRight="265dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create_replen_request_products_required_header_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/create_replen_request_products_required_text"
        android:textColor="@color/app_white_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_call_products_description_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/create_replen_request_products_required_header_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/create_replen_request_products_required_header_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:text="@string/create_replen_request_description_text"
        android:textColor="@color/app_white_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/create_replen_request_add_product_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add_call_products_description_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/create_replen_request_products_required_header_text"
        android:src="@drawable/add_item"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/create_add_product_btn_desc"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create_replen_request_quantity_requested_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/create_replen_request_add_product_btn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/create_replen_request_add_product_btn"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="@string/create_replen_request_quantity_text"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:textColor="@color/app_white_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/create_replen_request_unit_cost_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/app_white_color"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/create_replen_request_quantity_requested_textview"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/create_replen_request_quantity_requested_textview"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/create_replen_request_quantity_requested_textview"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/create_call_unit_cost_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado, en la parte donde el texto se sobreponia he cambiado un par de parametros.

Dejo el codigo por si a alguien le ayuda o le sirve de guia.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/pscrollview_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```